# kubectl Please enter Username: error: EOF

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I started getting an error in my CI process `Please enter Username: error: EOF` when running `kubectl` commands. 
The kubectl version matches the cluster version, and I can run the same commands fine from my machine with the same configuration shown by `kubectl config view`.

Here are the logs:

```
+ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
  name: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
    user: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
  name: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
current-context: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: REDACTED_FOR_QUESTION
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
++ echo 'Starting Kube proxy - port is 8001'
++ set +e
++ echo 'using kubectl'
++ sleep 1
++ kubectl proxy --port=8001
error: EOF
++ cat backingfile
++ rm backingfile
++ set -e
+ echo Starting Kube proxy - port is 8001 using kubectl Please enter Username:
Starting Kube proxy - port is 8001 using kubectl Please enter Username:
+ kubectl version
Please enter Username: error: EOF
Exited with code 1
```

What I am doing in my script is the following:

```
  echo "using kubectl"
  kubectl proxy --port=${KUBECTL_PROXY_PORT} > backingfile &
  sleep 1 && cat backingfile && rm backingfile
  set -e
```

As this allowed me to launch `kubectl` in the background but still get the logs of the command.

What is causing this error and how can I run the command successfully again? `Please enter Username: error: EOF`

Comment: Review your `config` file is properly formed.

I started receiving this and in my case the cause was that I edited the `config` file, but by mistake I added twice the `users` section, only the last one was taken in consideration and that didn't include the user I needed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are pointing to the different `KUBECONFIG` files:

**1**. You should verify your `KUBECONFIG` varaible,

**2**. You can add in your script `--kubeconfig=absolute_path_to_the_KUBECONFIG_file` flag

**3** You combine those above with `kubectl config --kubeconfig=XXXX use-context xxxx`

Please follow [Define clusters, users, and contexts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts)

Hope this help.

Comment: I will try, however at the moment when I do a `kubectl config view` in CI the config matches what I expect . Also the output of `kubectl config view` is exactly the same in CI and on my local machine, and where the next commands work perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: Please add this command into your script and will see if there is no env variables misconfiguration or other issue, and please try the second method using `--KUBECONFIG` file.

Comment: Sadly I still get the same messages for both (1) and (2) `Please enter Username: error: EOF`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: please add at the begging of your script `kubectl config view` and additional variables you are using in your system or env like: `KUBECONGFIG` ... verify the ouptut. It looks like miss-configuration problem.  This link can be [helpful](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps) please follow also [KUBECONFIG environment variable and Merging kubeconfig files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#the-kubeconfig-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gitlab environment variables, for exemplo, you should look if variables names are correct.